# Exceptions with applications using Sound after installing JMF

Tags: java, jmf

I have windows vista OS..
I Installed JMF to work with it.. but it seems I'm having some conflicts between Sound and JMF.. because after I installed JMF my projects that use Sound.. midi.. sequences.. are giving exceptions that they don't have some sound classes and so.. and when I removed JMF every thing went OK !!
so what I'm gonna do?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, JMF can do everything Sound can do, and much more, and better.

If you're going to be using JMF anyway, why not upgrade to a single, more powerful API?

Is this something you could try or would it be too painful to adapt your existing code?

Comment: OK, understood. Unfortunately I have no experience at getting these 2 libs to play nice together, so no more advice from me, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

JMF is pretty old, it has not been updated for a long time. If you still want to use Meida Framework in java. I recommend you using QuickTime Java framework - QTJava.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [Xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler), a non-JMF alternative.